# Python threads seems to be frozen

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I have a web crawler. Here is the code for it.

```py
# I truncated this code because of the comment.
from threading import Thread

no_of_threads = int(input("No. of threads : "))
if no_of_threads > 70:
    no_of_threads = 70
threads = []



def log(data, thid, info=True):
    if info:
        # print a information to the user
    else:
        # inform user about the error


def crawl(t_id):
  # Here comes the long-time loop. this will run until there are no items left in the list of URLs to be scraped
  while True:
        # do some complex operations like getting the title, description, etc.

lines = # a one million links list got from a file

for line in lines:
    # Get each link in the list and put in the list

# Iterate through the no. of threads given by user and create a thread
for _ in range(no_of_threads):
    t = Thread(target=crawl, args=(_,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

It instantiates the number of threads inputted by the user. Then in a forever, while loop it is crawling the URLs.

I ran this for about 4 hours and at first, all threads worked but after 4 hours only one thread is working. At last, it also became inactive.
Why is that?

Comment: try to boil down the code to the minimum number of lines to reproduce the problem, please. see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to do it. It's hard to help you given the sheer volume of code in your problem.

Comment: @Arne I did it, check it again.

Comment: That's a good effort already, but it's not reproducible yet. If I paste that code in a file and try to run it on my machine, I'll get a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure multithreading is going to help much here? Threads in Python are artificial, and do not execute in parallel as they all run on a single core. You likely won't notice much of a performance increase using Python threads. Maybe look into the `multiprocessing` library if you need parallelism. Otherwise, try removing the threading portion to see if the code works without it.

Comment: @CaitLAN Jenner thanks